# RSVP warning: ID "data" is not configured

Tags: network, cisco-commands, transport-protocol, gns3, rsvp

I am trying to follow this document: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/qos/configuration/guide/12_2sr/qos_12_2sr_book/config_rsvp.pdf
to configure rsvp, using gns3, for `Entering Senders or Receivers in the RSVP Database`.

I am using gns3 for the first time this semester and have very poor knowledge about rsvp.
Before that when I give this command: `ip rsvp policy local identity data` on page 15.
It gives me warning saying:
RSVP warning: ID "data" is not configured.
I am giving "data" as any string.

Can someone tell me how to configure RSVP ID, please?